# How do i display an image without its background in windows 8 html5 modern UI?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have an image which i want to display on a html5 page.when i display the image on the page , the image's background which is white square background also appears.I only want the actual image shape to appear on the page.

I have given the link for a similar image below.In this image i just want the round shape in green color and its arrow inside it and not its square shape white background .

any idea how to display just the actual image and not the other.

http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=next+icon&view=detail&id=F55BB11D07B0F03037054A4112AE608758BDB56D&FORM=IDFRIR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image has to be a transparent PNG for that to work. And also you have to remove it's background color on that `img` tag if it has

eg:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px; background-color:#000">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Next-icon.png" style="background: none;" border="0" alt="" />
</div>
```